# Error creating a function on Dart as a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:math';

 main() {
var minhaFnPar = () => print("O valor e par!"); 
var minhaFnImPar = () => print("O valor e impar!")
 
 executar(fnPar: minhaFnPar, fnImpar: minhaFnImpar);
}

void executar({Function fnPar, Function fnImpar}) {
  Random().nextInt(10) % 2 == 0 ? fnPar() : fnImpar();
}
```

The mistake its in `minhaFnImpar`, that its showing blue and red lines,blue one saying that isn't used,
red line saying its undefined name.

I've tried to create if & else, and put Random there, but still not working, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: please format your code so we can help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was due to spelling mistake of minhaFnImPar which you had misspelled as minhaFnImpar. Please see the correct code below :

```
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var minhaFnPar = () => print("O valor e par!");
  var minhaFnImPar = () => print("O valor e impar!");

  executar(fnPar: minhaFnPar, fnImpar: minhaFnImPar);
}

void executar({Function fnPar, Function fnImpar}) {
  Random().nextInt(10) % 2 == 0 ? fnPar() : fnImpar();
}
```

Comment: thank you men. I'm a little bit embarassed with such mistake, am a rookie in the programming world, im currently learning the basics of Dart, thank's again for your answer.

Comment: Are you using a different language keyboard. Both the names seemed same visually but the IDE kept complaining.